# How can I best connect Seam and GWT in a stateful web application?

Tags: java, gwt, jboss, seam, java-ee-5

We have a web application that was implemented using GWT. What it presents is fetched from a Jboss/Seam server using the remoting mechanism, and this works fine. However, the application is now extended to support sessions and users. The Seam GWT service doesn't seem to provide a way to let me log in such that Seam can return restricted data back to the GWT application, and so it looks to me that I will have to wrap the GWT application in facelets.

It is not obvious to me that a login using the Seam session mechanism will help me get correct data into the GWT application however, so my question is whether I will be lucky and it will just work, or if I need to do some client side magic, server side magic or if my perception of missing login functionality in the Seam GWT service actually is wrong.

Bonus points to anyone that can provide me with a complete example showing something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that things are "just working" as I hoped. By using Seam's Identity and login mechanism, I can access the current logged in user via `Identity.instance().getUsername();` in the service code that gets requests from the GWT portion of the application.

I tried to put a `@Restrict` annotation on the service, but this did not appear to work, however this is not something that is not needed as long as I can provide results to the GWT application based on the logged in user.

Answer (score -1):

How about this complete GWT app on google code -- http://code.google.com/p/tocollege-net/ ?

Comment: Since the interaction with Seam is an important aspect of the problem, I don't see how this particular project helps.